# Can't boot after cloning system to SSD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, disk-cloning

I'm trying to migrate a Windows install to a SSD. The current HDD contains installs for both Windows and Ubuntu, as well as data partitions.

The SSD is smaller than the HDD, so I copied each partition individually using the Linux's dd tool, instead of coping the whole drive.

The HDD partitions were:

```
 -UEFI
 -Windows system
 -Windows recovery
 -Linux system
 -Linux swap
 -Linux data
 -Windows data
```

And the SSD:

```
 -UEFI
 -Windows system
 -Windows recovery
 -Linux system
 -Linux swap
```

The partitions are GPT on both drives.

Initially the system would boot using the old drive if it was connected and give a 'device not connected' blue screen error if it wasn't. The Windows Boot Manager was still pointing to the old drive, so after using bcdedit to change the drive, the system starts to boot but gets stuck in a black screen with spinning dots.

I also noticed that in the recovery environment the HDD partitions were assigned earlier letters, so the old windows partition is C:, while the new one is F:. Swapping the sata connections put then in the 'correct' order, but didn't solve the booting problem

The possible problems I have identified:
*The system is stuck on the black screen with spinning dots. After a while the monitors will turn of until I move the mouse or press a key, but otherwise there was no change even after a couple hours.
*When entering the recovery environment (by restarting three times), the recovery partition being used is the HDD one. If I attempt to start in the recovery environment with the HDD unconnected, I get the 'device not connected' blue screen. After changing the sata I always get the blue screen, but pressing f1 starts the recovery environment anyway if the HDD is connected.